# How do I make android layout margin auto-adjust to the length of the page

Tags: android, xml

So in my `activity_page.xml`, I have this originally `android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"` in my bottom-most linear layout. It works for most pages, but in some cases where the article is too long, some of the elements disappear and I have to change the size to at 100dp or 125dp for the elements to appear again, but in the cases where the article is shorter, the extra whitespace becomes obnoxious. Is there a way to automatically adjust the size?

Comment: Why dont you use scrollview as parent.It adjusts the view if the screen is small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use scroll view.

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```